# How to format MySQL datetime to angular2 useable date format in Ionic 2?

Tags: mysql, angular, ionic2

I am trying to format a mysql datetime that looks like this: **2016-05-27 20:17:45** to an useable date format for angular2. After reading some comments how this could be done I created a custom pipe:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateToIso'
})
export class DateToIso {
    transform(value, args) {
        let newValue = new Date(value).toISOString();
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

Then I imported the pipe to the page where to use it  and defined it in the decorator to use it in the HTML file.

```
import {DateToIso} from '../../pipes/date-ToIso';
...
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
    pipes: [DateToIso]
})
```

When using the new created pipe in the HTML file: `{{ post[2] | dateToIso}}` I get the error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'dateToIso' could not be found

What am I doing wrong? Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing comma after the template url

```
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',  // << this comma here
    pipes: [DateToIso]
})
```

Comment: After that i get the error Cannot find module '@angular2/core' from 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\tester\app\pipes' in the console so i changed the import from to 'ionic-angular' and now i get the error TypeError: (0 , _ionicAngular.Pipe) is not a function

Comment: @A.Ilazi It should be `@angular/core`, without `2`